# Ocaml efficient quicksort

Tags: ocaml, quicksort

I'd like to know how can write an efficient version of quicksort  **where list is partitioned in one pass**.

I've this fragment of code,

```
    let rec quicksort' = function
[] -> []
| x::xs -> let small = List.filter (fun y -> y < x ) xs
           and large = List.filter (fun y -> y > x ) xs

in quicksort' small @ (x :: quicksort' large);;
```

but here I'm going through the list more than 1 time (calling 2 times quicksort for small and large) .

The idea is to do it in **just one step** without going to the list more than 1 time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[List.partition](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) is the way to go:

```
let rec quicksort = function
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> let smaller, larger = List.partition (fun y -> y < x) xs
               in quicksort smaller @ (x::quicksort larger)
```

Notice that `List.partition` helps avoid one redundant traversal through `xs`. You still have to sort the smaller part and the larger part recursively since it's the way Quicksort works.

I have to say that this version of `quicksort` is far from efficient. [Quicksort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is an inherent in-place algorithm which mutates an input array recursively. Another factor is pivot selection; choosing the first element as the pivot is not always a good idea.

These factors lead to an extremely different implementation for efficiency (probably using `Array` and mutation). Quicksort on `List` should be used for demonstrating the idea of the algorithm and the beauty of its recursion.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to write an efficient sort function, you may want to read this insightful paper: [Engineering a sort function](http://www.cs.fit.edu/~pkc/classes/writing/samples/bentley93engineering.pdf). Otherwise, I'm pretty sure [List.sort](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) is pretty well-written too.